# If you add all numbers from 1 to 400 how much will you get?$ 1+2+3.....398+399+400$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If you add all numbers from $1$ to $400$ how much will you get? $$1+2+3.....398+399+400=?$$

Comment: arithmetic sequence?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to see why the arithmetic sequence formula (mentioned by others) works is by observing
$$ 2( 1 + 2 + ... + 400 ) = (1 + 400) + (2 + 399) + (3 + 398) + ... + (400 + 1) = 401 + 401 + ... + 401 = 400(400 + 1).$$
Then divide both sides by $2$ to obtain. 
$$  1 + 2 + ... + 400  =  \frac{400(400 + 1)}{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Simple arithmetic progression:
 $$\frac{1+400}{2}\cdot400  \quad =\quad 80200$$

Answer (score 2):

Simply
$$1+2+\dots+400=\frac{400(400+1)}{2}=80200$$